# Transaction rollback not happening in Completeable Future

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, asynchronous

I am trying to call a method asynchronously  with the help of completeableFuture in java

Like below:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.Required,readOnly=false)
public boolean updateStatusandMove(){
//update value in database
//move file via rest service

}
```

Now , this method is called asynchronously , with multiple completeable futures.
Some completaable future fails and some succeeds depending on availability of folder while moving file. For the ones who fails due to moving file httpserver exception is thrown, database values which were updated before moving should be rolled back, but it doesn't happen. So in short transactional rollback does not happen in completeable future. but if this method synchronously without completeable future , then rollback happens. Transactional annotation is used and it is spring boot application.

```
    ExecutorsService service=Executors.newFixedThreadpool(50);
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    
    Callable<CompletebleFuture<Boolean>> task=()->getcompletefuture(requestValues) //values from request will be passed
    
    Future<CompleteableFuture<Boolean>>  ftr=service.submit(task);
    
    }
    
    public CompleteableFuture<Boolean> getcompletefuture(requestValues){
    
    Boolean ac=updateStatusandMove();
    return CompleteableFuture.completedFuture(ac);
    
    }

 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.Required,readOnly=false)
    public boolean updateStatusandMove(){
    //update value in database
    //move file via rest service
    
    }
```